# Help with complicated math and syntax

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to create a calculator for this mobile game that I play (Lord’s Mobile) but cant seem to figure out the formula.

1) In this game, you can get your upgrade time reduced when your guild members press a “help” button.

2) A single “help” reduces your current time by 1%. So if someone presses help, your time (X) = (Time-(Time*0.1)). When another person presses help, it would be Y = (X-(X*0.1)), then Z=(Y-(Y*0.1)), so on and so forth, where each new letter represents the new time.

Another example: If your total time is 24 hours (1,444 minutes):

- Help 1 would be (1,444-(1,444*0.1)=1,300min left;
- Help 2 would be (1,300-(1,300*0.1)=1,170min left (and so on).

3) There is a minimum (or maximum?): Once 1 minute > 1%, it reduces by 1 minute instead.

4) Castles can be levels 1-25. The amount of helps you can receive depends on your castle level. The amount increases consecutively, with Lvl 1 being 5 times, and 25 being 30 times.

With all of these factors, I can’t seem to figure out how to calculate this in my spreadsheet. Even without the additional factors, I was at least trying to figure out how to do the whole “1% Reduction” in one cell.

I was hoping some math genius might see this. And even without the math help, I’m posting this here because I don’t know the correct syntax. Anyone have a clue as to what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Sara, it doesn't look like you need a math genius but a dev. Your need is a conditionnal formula with `=IF`; Don't hesitate to share a sample with desired results, conditions, etc.. for us to better understand and help you. Moreover there are a lot of communities out there for this game and i'm sure someone already made this kind of spreadsheet. I found this : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HDecOtw8K4X2Kn9mgOBJPRLBBQMmcBIgmVkAzmloj3M/edit#gid=1723866245

Comment: Stop thinking about spreadsheets, they are not the tool for this. This is just programming code and needs a programming language. In that context, spreadsheets can be *at most* a tool to prototype or illustrate something. So that makes this a programming question, but I'm unsure if it belongs on [SO] or [softwareengineering.se] (probably the latter, it's purely an algorithm issue). If you place is there it needs more effort like Paul suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems in your examples: 24 hours is 1440 minutes.

Also you say 1% but then your example shows that you are calculating a 10% reduction.

- If you want a 10% reduction just multiply  x*0.9
- if it is a 1% reduction just multiply x*0.99

> 3) There is a minimum (or maximum?): Once 1 minute > 1%, it reduces by
>   1 minute instead.

you need to include an if statement. assuming the previous value is in cell b7

for a 1% reduction:

```
   =if(b7<100,b7-1,b7*0.99)
```

for a 10% reduction

```
   =if(b7<10,b7-1,b7*0.9)
```

> 4) Castles can be levels 1-25. The amount of helps you can receive
>   depends on your castle level. The amount increases consecutively, with
>   Lvl 1 being 5 times, and 25 being 30 times.

I have no idea what that means in relation to the previous requirements.